# Aggregate pairs in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am on framework 4.0. This is a WPF application, on sql server CE, which is a little limiting.
I have an entity that looks like this:

```
    public class TimeEvent
    {
       public int Id
       {get; set;}
       public DateTime EventDate
       {get; set;}
       public bool CheckIn
       {get; set;}
    }
```

I have two types of events, one for checkin (`CheckIn` is true) and one for checkout (`CheckIn` is false). Each of the events happens once per day.
What I want to do using linq to entities, is to end up with a set of objects like this:

```
public class Diff
{
   public DateTime Date //The date of both events
   {get; set;}
   public DateTime CheckInTime //Time of first event
   {get; set;}
   public DateTime CheckOutTime //Time of second event
   {get; set;}
   public int Hours //Difference in hours.
   { get { return (CheckOutTime - CheckInTime).Hours;} 
}
```

There are validation rules in place so no more than one event of each type can happen in one day.
I tried using the aggregate function, but I'm really not getting anywhere.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to GroupBy them by EventDate.Date first?

Comment: @Bond - Nope. Didn't think about that. I locked on aggregate. I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, especially since AFAIK `Aggregate` isn't supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: it has to be `return(CheckOutTime - CheckInTime).Hours;`

Comment: Is `Id` unique to every `TimeEvent` or is it a foreign key? i.e. does you `TimeEvents`? entity log data about just one instance? Please show us your failed attempt so we can see your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your time events by `EventDate` date part. To get that you need to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` method (simple `EventDate.Date` will not work with Entity Framework).

```
var query = from t in db.TimeEvents
            group t by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.EventDate) into g
            let checkIn = g.Min(x => x.EventDate)
            let checkOut = g.Max(x => x.EventDate)           
            select new Diff {
                Date = g.Key,
                CheckInTime = checkIn,
                CheckOutTime = checkOut                    
            };
```

Also you can calculate time difference on server side with `EntityFunctions.DiffHours(checkOut, checkIn)`.

Comment: I was going to comment about the `TruncateTime` function :) Thank you. I will try it out.

Comment: Did a little modifying to get it to work with SQL Server CE. Thanks!

Comment: @EladLachmi glad that I helped you :) Btw can you tell which part is not supported by SQL Server CE (just to know for future) ?

Comment: `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` does not work for CE. I had to use `group t by new { t.EventDate.Day, t.EventDate.Month, t.EventDate.Year } into g`. With this modification, g.Key also decomes a problem. Since I don't really need it, I just dropped it.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you have a list of `TimeEvent` s(`List<TimeEvent>`), I will consider it as `timeEvents`.

All my code is given below.

```
    List<TimeEvent> timeEvents = new List<TimeEvent>();

                    //dummy values.
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    {
                        timeEvents.Add(new TimeEvent() { Id = i, EventDate = now, CheckIn = false });
                        now = now.Add(TimeSpan.Parse("3:1"));
                        timeEvents.Add(new TimeEvent() { Id = i, EventDate = now, CheckIn = true });
                        now = now + TimeSpan.Parse("1");
                    }

                    //group by 
                    var dataSet = timeEvents.GroupBy(a => a.EventDate.Date);
                    List<Diff> diffs = new List<Diff>();
                    foreach (var x in dataSet) 
                    {
                        if (!(x.Count() == 1))
                        {
                            diffs.Add(new Diff() { Date = x.ElementAt(0).EventDate.Date, CheckInTime = (x.ElementAt(0).CheckIn == true) ? x.ElementAt(0).EventDate : x.ElementAt(1).EventDate, CheckOutTime = (x.ElementAt(0).CheckIn == false) ? x.ElementAt(0).EventDate : x.ElementAt(1).EventDate });

                        }

                    }

                    //diffs list is full. now you can use the diffs as you like :)
```

Comment: What the point of copying class definitions from question? And where is the Linq to entities?

Comment: I changed it.:) thanks. I have queried it on the the list of TimeEvent

Comment: Still no Linq to Entities :) You are using Linq to Objects here

Comment: Oh, I can see now, I can not just group by on `EventDate.Date`. I still did not get linq to entities and linq to objects :(

Comment: Yep. And `ElementAt` also not supported by Linq to Entities. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yes, but this code works. I checked it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever aggregate delegate you create it will need to be converted to SQL by EF. Even if your data is perfectly clean and ordered with this will be a challange. Why not just use this.

```
static IEnumerable<Diff> GetDiffs(YourContext context)
{
    bool? checkedIn;
    DateTime lastDate;
    foreach (var event in context.TimeEvents.OrderBy(te => te.EventDate))
    {
        if ((checkedIn.HasValue && checkedIn.Value = !event.CheckIn) ||
                (!checkedIn.HasValue && event.CheckIn))
        {
            if (checkedIn.HasValue && !event.CheckIn)
            {
                yield return new Diff
                    {
                        CheckInTime = lastDate;
                        CheckOutTime = event.EventDate;
                    };
            }                    

            checkedIn = event.CheckIn;
            lastDate = event.EventDate;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, it doesn't matter where your data starts or if it doesent flip flop correctly. I've also ignored your spurious `Diff.Date` property. It doesn't handle a checked in period bridging day boundries.